# Wrong timing on animation + sprite flip on Unity;

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I need to set an animation of flipping in a 2D game on Unity. How is the best way to do this?

I'm trying something like this pseudo code:

```c#
void FixedUpdate() { 
    if(lastSide!=currentSide)
        flip();
}

void flip() {
    if(lastSide == 1) // if is facing right
        animator.SetTrigger("flipToLeft");
    else if(lastSide == -1) // if is facing left
        animator.SetTrigger("flipToRight");

    this.player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(lastSide * -1, 1f, 1f);
}
```

This "works", but the sprite is fliping before the animation of fliping starts.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to hardcode a delay for the point at which you want the sprite to flip:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{ 
     if(lastSide != currentSide)
         StartCoroutine(Flip());
}

IEnumerator Flip()
{
    if(lastSide == 1) // if is facing right
         animator.SetTrigger("flipToLeft");

    else if(lastSide == -1) //if is facing left
         animator.SetTrigger("flipToRight");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f); // delay before flipping sprite
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(lastSide*-1,1f,1f);
}
```

If you don't want to hardcode the timing, you can look into [Animation Events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html) which you can use to call functions directly from the animation.

Answer (score -3):

You can use DoTween for fliping in simple way.